# Java: extract Alpha Channel from BufferedImage

Tags: java, alpha

I would like to extract the Alpha Channel from a bufferedimage and paint it in a separate image using greyscale. (like it is displayed in photoshop)

Answer (score 5):

Not tested but contains the main points.

```
public Image alpha2gray(BufferedImage src) {

    if (src.getType() != BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB)
        throw new RuntimeException("Wrong image type.");

    int w = src.getWidth();
    int h = src.getHeight();

    int[] srcBuffer = src.getData().getPixels(0, 0, w, h, (int[]) null);
    int[] dstBuffer = new int[w * h];

    for (int i=0; i<w*h; i++) {
        int a = (srcBuffer[i] >> 24) & 0xff;
        dstBuffer[i] = a | a << 8 | a << 16;
    }

    return Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(new MemoryImageSource(w, h, pix, 0, w));
}
```

Comment: I think the shifts in the assignment need to go the other way? `a | a << 8 | a << 16`

Comment: This does not compile. Line to fix:

  `int[] srcBuffer = src.getData().getPixels(0, 0, w, h, (int[]) null);`

Comment: @vbence I didn't know I could edit it, thanks. I see you edited it yourself

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe there's a single method call to do this; you would have to get all the image data and mask off the alpha byte for each pixel. So for example, use `getRGB()` to get the ARGB pixels for the image. The most significant byte is the alpha value. So for each pixel in the array you get from `getRGB()`,

```
int alpha = (pixel >> 24) & 0xFF;
```

Comment: ok, thanks. how would i mask off the alpha byte from one pixel?

Comment: I think this is possible without manually looping over the pixels which might result in better performance on some platforms, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could [grab the Raster](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRaster%28%29) from the BufferedImage, and then [create a child](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/image/Raster.html#createChild%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%5B%5D%29) Raster of this one which contains only the band you're interested in (the `bandList` parameter). From this child raster you can create a [new BufferedImage](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#BufferedImage%28java.awt.image.ColorModel,%20java.awt.image.WritableRaster,%20boolean,%20java.util.Hashtable%29) with a suitable `ColorModel` which would only contain the grayscale aplpha mask.

The benefit of doing it this way instead of manually iterating over the pixels is that the runtime has chance to get an idea of what you are doing, and thus this *might* get accelerated by exploiting the hardware capabilities. Honestly I doubt it will be accelerated with current JVMs, but who knows what the future brings?