# Identify whether a Png image has 100 percent transparent Background

Tags: java, image, imagemagick, png

I am trying to write a code where I get a png/jpeg image. If it is a png image, I want to check if it's background is 100% transparent. If yes, I want to add white background using image magick.

Currently I use image magick's "identify -format %A new.png" which returns true or false based on transparency.

However, is there any way to find out 100 percent background transparency using image magick or java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate over each pixel in the image and check whether the most significant byte (which is the alpha channel) is zero (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176560/java-extract-alpha-channel-from-bufferedimage)).
Do it somehow like this:

```
public static boolean isFullyAlpha(File f) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(f);
    for(int y = 0; y < img.getHeight(); y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < img.getWidth(); x++) {
            if(((img.getRGB(x, y) >> 24) & 0xFF) != 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I understand your solution, but  the code written here returns false for any image. Can you please provide the correct code?

Comment: I checked the alpha values and for the tranparent image,it was 6 and for the non transparent ones it was 255. SO the method requires little tweaking, but its working fine.
Maybe a check if alpha is 255 then return true, else false

Comment: I checked it using `BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://www.cityrider.com/fixed/43aspect.png"));` in the second line and it works just fine, returning true. Maybe your image isn't really fully alpha? Then you might want to check if it less than a threshold. (So don't compare for != 0 in the if-statement but check for <= 10 or some similiar value)

Comment: Checking for the alpha to be 255 and then to return true is generally a bad idea for two reasons: First: Even on fully transparent images you will have to iterate over the whole image before being able to exit the loops which will result in always being the worst-case-scenario, second, which is much more significant: If you are testing an image having pixel which are not fully alpha, it will also fail. I think the answer supplies everything you need to form a good approach to your specific problem. Just tweak it as needed.

Comment: Absolutely right. I would vote you up but I dont have required reputation level . :)
Thanks for the help nonetheless

Comment: Bear in mind that `ImageIO.read()` (at least the default reader that comes with Oracle JRE 7) does not recognize transparency for true-colour (or gray) images (variant 2b : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569887/libpng-palette-png-with-alpha-or-not/13570973#13570973 ) It's not very frequent, though.